# PHP Singleton Database Restrictions

Tags: php, singleton

Okay, so this is cropping up alot, and I figured i'd ask some of the wise people over at Stack Overflow to help me out here.

I have read up that you should use the Singleton Pattern when you want to create a database connections in order to return one instance. This is all well and good, but doesn't this restrict you to only one connection? Since the singlton only returns a single instance of an object.

So say I had a method that return the single instance of a class contrustor that constructor created a connection based on the paramteres specified by the user, or say in a configuration file, and then user would want to create a second connections to another database, wouldn't the singleton just return the original connection, therefore it restricts the user from creating multiple database connections?

Comment: Where did you read this sage advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the implementation in various ways including:

1) The singleton holds onto member data including a connection to database A and another member variable containing a connection to database B.

2) Same as #1 but let's say you want a pool of connections to each database so then you would hold onto 2 arrays containing the connections.  Of course these can all be connected at once, but better yet you would lazy-connect them but maintaining this array (to some max number of connections).

Comment: Hmm I see, so for #1 you would have two members and your getInstance method would generally return both instances?

Comment: well - really it would just return one instance of the singleton and that singleton would contain something like getConnectionA() and getConnectionB().  If you have multiple things going on you will want to make sure only one process/thread/user is using ConnectionA...so you would either make them block (wait) or more likely you would have a pool of connections.  So calling getConnectionA() from the singleton would return a valid connection from the pool.  You would make sure that connections are returned to the pool after use and you never hit the max.

Comment: I see, so in essence you have two methods, designed for connection to different databases? or have I totally misunderstood your concept

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Singleton` pattern to create a `Connections` class. It is up to you how many connections this class manages for example you could keep one connection or you could use an object pool type pattern to manage a pool of connections.